# What is the formal definition of line of best fit for a finite set of points?

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a finite set $S$ of points in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $S$ has cardinality greater than or equal to $2$. What is the rigorous definition of the line of best fit associated with $S$? Also, does every finite set of points with cardinality greater than or equal to $2$ have a unique line of best fit?

Comment: This is not ordinary least squares, it is the best fit line, not linear approximation.

Comment: When you write “best fit”, it is not clear to me what exactly you are optimizing for. Sum of squared (orthogonal) distances is a common objective, but not the only possible one. That objective would be part of a rigorous definition, so I assume there is a fair chance you don't have a clear objective either. In that case the use case would be important to evaluate objectives.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you mean by best fit line.

Let us suppose, as an example, that you have the vector $x=(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ and $y=(-9,-4,-6,-3,-2,-1,2,3,5,3,7,4,8)$ and you want to find a line $p(x)=a+bx$ in the following three cases:

1. [Ordinay least square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) means to find $a$ and $b$ such that $\sum (p(x_i)-y_i)^2$ is minimum.
2. [Non-negative least square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) means to find $a$ and $b$ such that $\sum (p(x_i)-y_i)^2$ is minimum, with $p(x_i)\geq y_i$.
3. You can use another norm. For instance, you can find $a$ and $b$ such that $\max|p(x_i)-y_i)|$ is minimum.

You can see the best line in each case [here](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/CXHuKKYmhEX).

There are other ways to find a line that "best fits" the data.

You can find many discussions on related subject searching for "[\(y(x)=a+bx\) best fit](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28y%28x%29%3Da%2Bbx%5C%29%20best%20fit%20)" on SearchOnMath, for instance.